# Why does Bash require closing some statements?

Tags: bash, shell, script, shell-script, bash-scripting

Something I've always wondered but never gotten around to asking. In Bash:

- `if` statements require an ending `fi`
- `case` statements require an ending `esac`
- `do` statements require an ending `done` (which apparently used to be `od` in pre-Bourne shells)

What is the reason that these are required in [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) when most full programming languages do not have equivalents, and why are they only required for certain statements? For example, why no `rof` for a `for` loop?

Comment: This may give some context: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell#Features_of_the_original_version

Comment: I think you will find that most full programming languages do in fact use some form of block delimiter. for instance in the pascal-family (C, C++, C#, Java, Javascript, etc)of languages blocks are generally delimited with `{` and `}`.  The only languages I know of that don't use block delimiters are languages that use whitespace like indents and line breaks to delimit blocks  (like Python or Whitespace), and you can't use whitespace effectively in a command prompt. all of the statements in your post are block statements that are likly to consist of multiple lines.

Comment: That's interesting, braces never occurred to me but I suppose they do have the same function.

Comment: @FrankThomas - I wouldn't call those languages the "Pascal family"; I'd call them the "C-family", with the Pascal family being languages like Pascal, Modula2, Modula3, Oberon, and just maybe modern BASICs, which tend to use words - usually BEGIN and END, sometimes the statement name and END/ENDxxx - where C-family languages use braces. But the general idea stands.

Comment: @FrankThomas - (_and arguably, the "Pascal family" could be called the "Algol family"._)

Comment: Although it doesn't really explain why statements like `for` and `while` don't have ending equivalents.

Comment: "While" and "for" don't because they take a do/done block.